# Android SearchView clear button misaligned

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview

I have implemented android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in menu.xml and it works good only if I use toolbar instead of action bar. When I use action bar the layout moves the X button of this widget slightly to the left, leaving blank space between the button and the right side of screen. This does not happen when I use the Toolbar. Please look at the screenshots and tell me what I can do.

I am using stock android Marshmallow.

This is how it looks using normal action bar.
[image: This is how it looks using normal action bar]

And this is how it looks using toolbar.
[image: And this is how it looks using toolbar]

This is menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.appsbyusman.ppc.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

And this is the relevant code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    mSearchViewAdapter = new SearchFeedResultsAdaptor(MainActivity.this, R.layout.search_feed_list_item, null, columns, null, -1000);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSearchViewAdapter);
    return true;
}
```

This is the activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.appsbyusman.ppc.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```